# ¿Cómo pongo la primera letra de cada nombre en mayúsculas y la segunda en minúsculas en celdas con mas de un dato? (oracle sql)

Tags: sql, oracle

En la tabla `users_view`, columna `first_name`, tengo registrados usuarios con 1 nombre, usuarios con 2 nombres, todo en mayúsculas, todo en minúsculas y también de ambas juntas.

Armé una query que convierte la primera letra en mayúsculas y desde la segunda en adelante lo convierte a minúsculas.

Esto funciona perfectamente para los usuarios que están registrados con un solo nombre, pero el problema lo tengo con los que tienen 2 nombres ya que el segundo nombre queda completo en minúsculas.

Ejemplo:

```
First_name
Juan francisco
```

El sql que armé es este:

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(m.moddte, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FECHA_MENSAJE,
    m.msg_id ID_MENSAJE,
    DECODE(m.msgtyp, '1', 'Shutdown', '2', 'Display and Shutdown', '3', 'Display', m.msgtyp) TIPO_MENSAJE,
    m.mod_usr_id USUARIO,
    UPPER(SUBSTR(u.first_name, 0, 1)) ||''|| LOWER(SUBSTR(u.first_name, 2)) NOMBRE,
    UPPER(SUBSTR(u.last_name, 0, 1)) ||''|| LOWER(SUBSTR(u.last_name, 2)) APELLIDO,
    m.msg MENSAJE
FROM    mtfmsg m
LEFT
JOIN    users_view u
ON  u.usr_id = m.mod_usr_id
WHERE   m.moddte >= (SYSDATE - 1 / 24 )
ORDER BY    m.moddte ASC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle incluye una función precisamente para hacer lo que describes. La función es [`INITCAP`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions083.htm#SQLRF00650).

```
select initcap(u.first_name) as nombre,
       initcap(u.last_name) as apellido
  from ...
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/WSRF62639)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Acotando a la respuesta de sstan, si el problema que tienes es que en el campo NOMBRE puede estar compuesto por mas de dos cadenas separadas por un espacio en blanco.  Lo que podrias hacer es lo siguiente en base al query que enviaste y el uso de initcap

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(m.moddte, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FECHA_MENSAJE,
    m.msg_id ID_MENSAJE,
    DECODE(m.msgtyp, '1', 'Shutdown', '2', 'Display and Shutdown', '3', 'Display', m.msgtyp) TIPO_MENSAJE,
    m.mod_usr_id USUARIO,
    initcap(substr(trim(u.first_name),0,instr(trim(u.first_name),' ')-1)) PRIMER_NOMBRE, 
    initcap(substr(trim(u.first_name),instr(trim(u.first_name),' ')+1,length(u.first_name)))SEGUNDO_NOMBRE,
    initcap(u.last_name),
    m.msg MENSAJE
FROM    mtfmsg m
LEFT
JOIN    users_view u
ON  u.usr_id = m.mod_usr_id
WHERE   m.moddte >= (SYSDATE - 1 / 24 )
ORDER BY    m.moddte ASC
```

espero te sirva